# What fissionable metals other than Uranium and Plutonium can I trade in TradeWars?

Tags: tradewars-2002

I would like to find a game where I can trade nuclear metals.

Tradewars looks pretty good for this.

What are the fissionable metals tradeable in TradeWars, as of this moment?

Comment: // , Follow-up question: Can I trade Thorium in game?

Comment: // , Regardless of what it "sonuds like", I think most people who read the question will realize that I am asking about a specific game, @Frank, because I am familiar with it, and want to know how to use a certain part of that. *specific*. game. The game is Tradewars. The little background bit about how I arrived at the question is *not* the question. Imagine a similar question: "I like modern FPS games with guns that use NATO rounds, so I installed Rainbow 6. What US Military guns with NATO rounds can I fight with in Rainbow 6?"

Comment: I would still highly recommend removing that part of the question, then.  While it's sort of relevant, I doubt I'd be the only one confused by how you're wording it.  I can certainly see where you're coming from, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

37coins.  This is JP, co-author of TW.  Thanks for the question.

TradeWars is a highly abstracted space trader.  All commodities are lumped into Ore, Organics and Equipment, without any additional detail.  At least for the classic game, that won't change.  Classic TradeWars isn't intended to be a simulation.  Combat is also highly abstracted.  This distinguishes it from most space trader/combat simulation games, even those inspired by it.  While I'm a big fan of realism in simulation (I currently work on Star Citizen writing the flight control systems for its ships), that's just not TradeWars.

In fact, if you're interested in a more realistic space trading/economics game, I'd recommend looking at Star Citizen.  We're working on the economic/trading aspects of the game right now, and my good friend Pete Mackay, who was an avid TradeWars player, is currently fleshing out the commodity list.  I'm assisting from the cargo-hauling side, where the economy intersects with flight mechanics, but won't have much influence beyond that.

Anyway, sorry I can't help with TW commodities.  I don't think it's going to provide what you're looking for.

- John Pritchett

Comment: // , Honestly, I think abstract is better. It's better to allow people to not have to learn "ticky tacky bits", and instead be creative. I am supremely honored to correspond with a Star Citizen developer. I really hope Star Citizen does not fall into the Mythical Man-Month problem. What game, then, was it that allowed trading in Uranium? I seem to remember a game much like TradeWars that allowed the trading of Uranium and Plutonium from back in the day. It was my first ever command line game, and looked sort of like this: http://eisonline.classictw.com/Images/TWScreen.png. So, not TW metals?